# Recommended way to deploy Otel collector agent based on regions

Tags: open-telemetry, telemetry, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry-collector, otel

We are using Open Telemetry SDK in our ASP.NET & WCF application [.NET Framework applications].

In my test server, run the Otel collector agent and configured to send traces to Grafana Cloud. The trace data's are able to see on the dashboard.

We want to deploy the otel collector agent on the Production system. Our production environment have 4 servers in each regions on AWS.

As of now we run the agent on the all the 4 servers in each regions and enabled public access to all the servers to check the traces. But usually won't allow public access to all the servers. only limited servers configured with public access.

**Scenario 1**,

Consider 3 servers does not have public access & 1 server have the public access.

So tried to send server 1,2,3 trace data to server 4 and server 4 send traces to grafana cloud, but getting the below error on server 1,2,3.

**server 1,2,3 config**

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: localhost:4317
      http:
        endpoint: localhost:4318

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: normal
  otlp:
    endpoint: 172.31.10.36:4317

processors:
  batch:

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]

  telemetry:
    metrics:
      address: 0.0.0.0:9999
```

Server 4 config

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
   otlp:
     endpoint: tempo-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net:443
     headers:
        authorization: Basic <API key base 64 string>

processors:
  batch:

service:    
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

> 2024-03-06T12:46:06.857Z        warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:195  [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "xx.xx.xx.xx:4317", ServerName: "xx.xx.xx.xx:4317", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:4317: i/o timeout"        {"grpc_log": true}

**Scenario 2**

All servers have public access & otel collector agent is running on all the servers.

**Any suggestions or recommended way to run the Otel collector agents based on the above scenarios?**